# Delphi, ClientDataSet and threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tclientdataset

I have a TClientDataSet that holds information and is **not** linked to any GUI component.

In a thread I locate the relevant record, go into edit mode and change the values. Because it happens inside a thread, I use TCriticalSection before locating until after posting. It looks something like that:

```
cs.Enter;
if not cds4Process.Locate('locator',locator,[]) then exit;
cds4Process.Edit;
cds4Process.FieldByName('field1').AsDateTime := pDay;
cds4Process.FieldByName('field2').AsFloat := amnt;
cds4Process.Post;
cs.leave;
```

cds4Process is located on the main form and it is not linked to any GUI component, I don't pass it as a parameter to the thread.

I execute the thread several times and in some point, I get an error that says that cds4Process is not in insert or edit mode. even though the above code sequence is the same in all the places I use cds4Process.

Any idea? What am I missing?

Comment: We don't have enough details here. Try to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance, are you touching the cds4Process component from the main GUI thread?

Comment: You did not leave the critical section if you cannot locate the record. Or is this just fake code?

Comment: @whosrdaddy, I don't touch it any place except for this thread.

Comment: @SirRufo, the cs.leave; is in the finally clause. I have this snippet in different places (if then else) so I pasted here a sample.

Comment: Is the ClientDataSet linked to any provider?

Comment: We can not see any finally clause in the posted code. Programmers first rule: Be precise. Second rule: Be more precise. There is no way to code `Well.something.like( perhaps );` and everything will happen you just thought of in the moment of coding. We are not able to look into your brain, so you have to be very precise here to get a very precise answer back

Comment: @UweRaabe - this cds is linked to nothing and its sole purpose is to hold the data for the thread

Comment: @SirRufo, I couldn't agree with you more but pasting here the full code was not a better option. I thought maybe there's a silly error that is causing it and I'm missing, i.e. I have to use synchronize for cds even if it's not linked to anything. I'm now re-organizing my code so either the problem will be fixed or I will post the new code here.

Answer (score 1):

I would place everything related to the TClientDataSet (its connection component, persistent fields etc.) on a TDataModule instead on the main form, and then create an instance of this data module in the thread.

Using this thread-bound TDataModule as a container for data access components would allow visual design, and prevent me from using the VCL main thread accidentally.